# How to confirm sun java 6's license agreement automatically?

Tags: package-management, java, debconf

When I install this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

I am still forced to select OK and YES during the install.

The -y switch doesn't work for this.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: [One direction to pursue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/expect.1.html), if you're up for an adventure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a file containing this line (columns separated by a tab):

  ```
  sun-java6-bin   shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1    boolean     true
  ```
- Import this into debconf with `sudo debconf-set-selections < file`.
- Install the packages